# Zoom out on webpage in ChromeDriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use `WebDriver 3.5.3` and `ChromeDriver 2.31` and try to zoom out on a webpage.

Following codes has no impact to page.

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SUBTRACT));
```

I tried to do it with `JavaScript` too.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom = '30%';");
```

Comment: Same code is work in FF. Starange

Comment: by the way question is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not specific with version, please downgrade Selenium to 3.0.1 version and it will work.

Edit1 : This is even working with the configuration you specified.
WebDriver 3.5.3 
ChromeDriver 2.31 
Chrome browser 60.0.3

Edit2 :

```
// open browser here
    driver.get("http://google.com");

    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jse.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom = '30%';");
```

Comment: Where it is write dear

Comment: @Chandra Shekhar: I use Chrome `61.0.3163.100`. Could you please share your code?

Comment: @ChandraShekhar : So it depends on the structure of the page. Any other solution?